# "Do the nails" or "get nails done"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, expressions

Which expression is more often said and heard in the US: "do the nails" or "get the nails done"?

For example, should I say "I'm doing my nails today" or "I'm getting my nails done today"? Which sound more natural to you? Or do would you use both expressions? Or is there another expression that is more often used when someone wants to say that she/he is going to the salon to do the manicure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two sentences have slightly different implications.

If you say to someone  **"I'm doing my nails today"**, they would assume you are painting your nails *yourself*. However, if you say **"I'm getting my nails done today"**, it implies that your nails are being painted by *someone else*.

Both sentences are used very often, but if you're getting your nails done at a salon, definitely use the second sentence.